# 'Download Master' not available on DSL-N55U router options despite showing on Asus doc website

Tags: router, adsl-router

Despite the fact that the Asus FAQ says that the 'Download Master' feature is available in Firmware 3.0.0.3.X and above ...

http://support.asus.com/FAQ/detail.aspx?SLanguage=en&m=DSL-N55U&p=11&s=2&os=&hashedid=aOKU9r3fCf3pyi95&no=3AA2723A-1A11-92FC-6D18-475703AA1F65

And the version on the router is 'Firmware Version:3.0.0.4.188' (the latest one)

The option of 'Download Manager' (as seen in the YouTube video linked from ASUSs site above) is not there - theres a new option 'Media Server' that isn't in the video - but no Download Manager.

Can anyone assist with getting this feature running please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out there are two chip sets for this model - and some of the features are not released for one the chip sets.  (They are available in the beta version though).

http://vip.asus.com/forum/view.aspx?id=20120917150805750&board_id=11&model=DSL-N55U&SLanguage=en-us